# Open jQuery accordion panel within jQuery tab-panel with outside link

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

On http://www.beautycenterelysee.be/behandeling-acne-microdermabrasie#tabs-5 I am using a jQuery accordion *inside a jQuery tab-panel*. My client wants to open the second panel on page-load with a link on another page. Is this possible?